# I can't file uploaded contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, file-type, multifile-uploader

I Want to create contact form
1.Only .psd and .ai files can be uploaded,other not allowed
2.Can send multiple files
3.Must have file size permission
4.Only members can fill in the form

How do I make this form?.psd and .ai file type how can add?Code that should be inserted into function.php?Can you show sample code?I'll be happy if you help. I'm new here.Thank you friends

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if the "*Contact 7*" plugin have such options. The "[WPForms](https://wpforms.com/)" plugin can be configured to fulfill all of your requirements. I am afraid that the only downside is that the plugin is paid. With such narrow requirements, I am afraid that there could be no option to use free plugin. I want just to make a clarification that, I am not affiliated with the *WPForms* plugin in any way. Just speaking from experience.

Other possible solution is to create plugin for your specific requirements. If you do not have the knowledge for this consider contacting certified web developer with knowledge in PHP and WordPress development.